# Get columns in a row to responsively break next to each other rather than filling horizontally

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a row with 6 columns that, when a screen gets smaller, I want to have break into 3 columns x 2 rows.

I came across a codepen that pretty much does this: https://codepen.io/davidsbaldwin/PdMqzB.

But, the codepen uses Bootstrap 3.3, and when I copy this CSS format to my Bootstrap 4 page, it doesn't work. Each column just gets spread out vertically, one below each other. Can you help?

```
<div class="container"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2 index-1"> 1 </div> <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 index-2"> 2 </div> <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-1 index-3"> 3 </div> <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2 index-4"> 4 </div> <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-1 index-5"> 5 </div> <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 index-6"> 6 </div> </div> </div>
```

SCREENSHOTS:

*Wide view:*[image: Wide screen] 
*How I want it to look on a small screen (as per the codepen):*
[image: How I want it to look]

*How my code currently renders as on a small screen:*

[image: How code currently looks]

How can I accomplish this? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, for XS and SM should use 4 columns for each DIV, for MD and LG it should use the other configuration.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"> 1 </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3"> 2 </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1"> 3 </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"> 4 </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1"> 5 </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3"> 6 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, what are classes index-N for?

Sorry, just read more about Bootstrap 4, this should be the code for it, last one was for Bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 col-md-2"> 1 </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-md-3"> 2 </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-md-1"> 3 </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-md-2"> 4 </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-md-1"> 5 </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-md-3"> 6 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed, that works, fantastic--thank you so very much!

Comment: Not a problem, please if you can, make my answer as useful.